# Run my app on Kitkat only

Tags: android

I want my application to run on Kitkat version only and not on any other android versions (neither older not newer), the below changes I have done in app level build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.tempapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

But this's not working..

Comment: any logs or problem you would like to share ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle it at two levels:

### Google play store level

You can make use of [android:maxSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#max). Which is an integer designating the maximum API Level on which the application is designed to run.  If the application's `maxSdkVersion` attribute is lower than the API Level used by the system itself, then the system will not allow the application to be installed.

Set value of this attribute to 19.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    maxSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    ...
}
```

**Note:**

This approach will only work if user is installing app through play store.

> Future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer check
>   or enforce the maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or
>   re-validation. Google Play will continue to use the attribute as a
>   filter, however, when presenting users with applications available for
>   download.

### App Level

The only alternative left is to enforce it in code. But the drawback is, user will be able to install the application but it will just stop itself. You can handle it gracefully as follows:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
    final AlertDialog compatibility = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("This app only be executed on Kitkat version")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null).create();
    compatibility.setCancelable(false);
    compatibility.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    compatibility.show();
    compatibility.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           compatibility.dismiss();
           finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Add this code in `onResume()`. You might want to add some extra checking in case user just minimizes the app and opens again and also dialog dismiss in `onDestroy()` to avoid crash due to memory leak

Comment: This works only if you use Google Play as distribution platform. There is no on-device-check: "Future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer check or enforce the maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or re-validation." https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#max

Comment: @Christopher Thanks for highlighting

Comment: @Sagar Thanks for the answer, but as you mentioned the drawback of it, now if user downloaded it from play store and sends that apk to the user with different API level, he/she can install it, I want to restrict that!!

Comment: @SiddharthThakkar Unfortunately its not possible any more. Best you can do is restrict app's usage

Answer (score 0):

*Solution 1 (I like this)*

Try blocking at app start up like this

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
    Log.i("No support", "This version is not supported.")
    finish();
}
```

*Solution 2*

Keep `minSdkVersion` and `maxSdkVersion` both to 19 like this

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.tempapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    maxSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: What about `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to run only in kitkat is written below code in your first activity

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
           //finish activity
 }
```